# Get value of XML node with condition using SQL server

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005

I have not worked with XML in the database before so I need some help.
I need to get the value where name equals "sv-SE" from the XML for a number of rows.

XML looks like this:
Row 1

```
<cultures>
  <culture name="sv-SE">Sverige</culture>
  <culture name="en-GB">Sweden</culture>
</cultures>
```

Row 2

```
<cultures>
  <culture name="sv-SE">Norge</culture>
  <culture name="en-GB">Norway</culture>
</cultures>
```

Expected output from this query would be

```
Sverige
Norge
```

When the name is "sv-SE"

```
select tblCountry.name.?? --XmlColumn
from tblCountry
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare @T table
(
  ID int identity,
  XMLCol xml
)

insert into @T values
('<cultures>
  <culture name="sv-SE">Sverige</culture>
  <culture name="en-GB">Sweden</culture>
</cultures>')

insert into @T values
('<cultures>
  <culture name="sv-SE">Norge</culture>
  <culture name="en-GB">Norway</culture>
</cultures>')

select XMLCol.value('(/cultures/culture[@name="sv-SE"])[1]', 'varchar(20)')
from @T
```

If you want different languages without rewriting the query you can use the [`sql:variable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188254.aspx) function.

```
declare @Lang varchar(5)
set @Lang = 'sv-SE'

select XMLCol.value('(/cultures/culture[@name=sql:variable("@Lang")])[1]', 'varchar(20)')
from @T
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time for me too ...
Try :

```
SELECT xmlCol.query('cultures//culture[@name=sv-SE]')   
FROM   myTable
```

Here is the [doc about querying XML columns with SQLServer2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Yep, I made a blind guess .... From looking at the other answer, I wasn't that far but still forgot some important stuff :) I put a +1 to the other answer right now !

Comment: Thanks for taking the time though